# How to give full access for LDAP users on a NFS volume?

Tags: linux, nfs, ldap, acl, nfsv4

I have a NFS volume which is mounted on a RHEL VM. I'm accessing the files via a LDAP server. When a LDAP `usera` accesses `somefile`, the same file can not be modified (for example, `touch`ed) by another LDAP user `userb`. The LDAP server is added as client on NFS server. I dont want to use root to `chmod 777` `somefile`.

How to give full permission for all LDAP users in the volume?

Example: here I have created a file named `71.pdf` as user `cs71`. But when the user `cs70` tries to access it, he gets permission denied.

```
[root@nfs]# su cs71@ldap.com
[cs71@nfs]$ touch 71.pdf
[cs70@nfs]$ ls -la
-rw------- 1 cs71 http 2 May 10 09:37 71.pdf
[cs71@nfs]$ echo "a" > 71.pdf
[cs71@nfs]$ exit
[root@nfs]# su cs70@ldap.com
[cs70@nfs]$ touch 71.pdf
touch: cannot touch ‘71.pdf’: Permission denied
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to this community! Please, [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/649060/edit) your question trying to better explain and clarify your problem. If you can, provide an example of what you are trying to do, showing what you would like to obtain.

Comment: Thanks for the example. Please, after the command `touch 71.pdf`, also show the output of `ls -la`.

Comment: Thanks for checking on this , 


    [cs70@cnfs]$ ls -la
    -rw-------   1 cs71    http         2 May 10 09:37 71.pdf

Comment: The output of `ls -la` should also include two lines, one ending with `.` and one ending with `..`. For example, if I run `ls -la` on `/tmp/somedir`, I obtain: `drwxrwxr-x  2 user users  4096 mag 10 15:43 .` and `drwxrwxrwt 19 root   root   36864 mag 10 15:43 ..`.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem may not be related to LDAP.

In Linux, a file has a *user owner* (the user who owns the file; usually, it is the user who created the file) and a *group owner*. The permissions regulate what operations can be performed by both. Your file `71.pdf` is:

```
-rw------- 1 cs71 http 2 May 10 09:37 71.pdf
```

The user who owns the file is `cs71`. The group who owns the file is `http`. According to the permissions `-rw-------`, only the user owner `cs71` can read/write the file. Anyone else (including users belonging to group `http`) can do nothing.

The ability to make a file readable/writeable by more than one user is provided by its `group` owner. If the `group` owner has some permissions on this file, all the users belonging to this group have the same permissions on the file.

**Case 1**

If `cs70` and `cs71` belong to group `http`, you can simply do:

```
[root@nfs]# su cs71@ldap.com
[cs71@nfs]$ chmod g+rw 71.pdf
```

or

```
[root@nfs]# su cs71@ldap.com
[cs71@nfs]$ chmod 660 71.pdf
```

**Case 2**

If `cs70` and `cs71` do not belong both to group `http`, but they belong both to another group `somegroup`, you can:

```
[root@nfs]# su cs71@ldap.com
[cs71@nfs]$ chgrp somegroup 71.pdf
[cs71@nfs]$ chmod g+rw 71.pdf
```

**Case 3**

If `cs70` and `cs71` do not have a group in common, you can ask the LDAP administrator to create it, and to add it ad a **secondary** group for both `cs70` and `cs71` (warning: it is **essential** that the group is **secondary** and that it **adds** to the groups `cs70` and `cs71` already belong to, **without** replacing them).